# What's the encoding for the Google main page?

Tags: perl, firefox

When Google's main page communicates with Firefox or Chrome it uses a particular type of encoding (Perl says it is `utf.64`). However, I can't decode it using such; is it a gzipped enconding? I need to finish an app in Perl that should be able to make sense of the Google homepage using Firefox (like a proxy).

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried so far?

Comment: If you're going to write a Perl app to communicate with "the Google homepage" you're violating their terms of service. You're supposed to get an API key and do it properly. And presumably this problem only came up because you're faking the UserAgent in the first place.

Comment: I was successfully able to decode the content using the library provided, however how do I encode it back to gzip; because if I deliver the decoded content back to the browser it will not work, because is expecting the gzipped content..

Comment: I was able to reencode using Compress::Zlib::memGzip kudos for the help !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using LiveHTTPHeaders:

```
http://www.google.com/

GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: www.google.com
User-Agent: ***
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.7,tr;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Accept-Charset: UTF-8,*
Keep-Alive: 115
Connection: keep-alive
Cookie: ***

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 18 Mar 2010 15:29:03 GMT
Expires: -1
Cache-Control: private, max-age=0
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Content-Encoding: gzip
Server: gws
Content-Length: 4440
X-XSS-Protection: 0
```

which shows that the data returned is gzipped and the character encoding used is UTF-8.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict; use warnings;
use LWP::UserAgent;

my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new();
$ua->show_progress(1);

my $response = $ua->get('http://google.com/');

if ( $response->is_success ) {
    print $response->decoded_content, "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you are employing LWP or something compatible, just use [HTTP::Message::decoded_content](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?HTTP::Message#%24mess-%3Edecoded_content%28%20%25options%20%29). Both content encoding and character encoding is figured out automatically for you.